# Consuming XML return selected date in order to XMLElements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to consume api which returns `XML`. 
The api url: [api](http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/a/)

This is how my `XML` classes looks:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ArrayOfExchangeRatesTable")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RootElement {

    @XmlElement(name="ExchangeRatesTable")
    private TableRateModel tableRateModel;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TableRateModel {

    @XmlElement(name="Table")
    private String table;
    @XmlElement(name="EffectiveDate")
    private Date effectiveDate;
    @XmlElement(name="Rates")
    private List<RateModel> rates;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RateModel {

    @XmlElement(name="Currency")
    private Currency currency;
    @XmlElement(name="Code")
    private String code;
    @XmlElement(name="Mid")
    private Double mid;
```

Then in the end I printed it and get a result as:

```
RootElement{tableRateModel=TableRateModel{table='A', effectiveDate=Thu Jul 20 00:00:00 CEST 2017, rates=[RateModel{currency=null, code='null', mid=null}]}}
```

Why the list of `Rates` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the XML-elements `Rate` is wrapped inside a element named `Rates`. I tested the following classes and got it to work

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ArrayOfExchangeRatesTable")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RootElement {
  @XmlElement(name = "ExchangeRatesTable")
  private TableRateModel tableRateModel;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class TableRateModel {
  @XmlElement(name = "Table")
  private String table;
  @XmlElement(name = "EffectiveDate")
  private Date effectiveDate;
  @XmlElement(name = "Rates")
  private Rates rates;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Rates {
  @XmlElement(name = "Rate")
  private List<Rate> rates;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Rate {
  @XmlElement(name = "Currency")
  private String currency;
  @XmlElement(name = "Code")
  private String code;
  @XmlElement(name = "Mid")
  private Double mid;
}
```

`Currency` is apparently not serializable because it doesn't have a parameterless contructor. One workaround is to add a getter that returns a `Currency`, parsed from the String:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Rate {
  @XmlElement(name = "Currency")
  private String currency;
  @Xml Element(name = "Code")
  private String code;
  @XmlElement(name = "Mid")
  private Double mid;

  public Currency getCurrency() {
    return Currency.getInstance(currency);
  }
}
```